# How can I update object in an array in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my array

```
const arr = [
{ id: "1", hello: "hello1" },
{ id: "2", hello: "hello2" },
```

];

I want this code

```
const finalarr = [
{ id: "1", hello: "hello1", bye: 'bye1' },
{ id: "2", hello: "hello2", bye: 'bye2' },
```

];

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Do you know how to add a prop to an object? How to loop over an array?

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe
I created this for object but I don't understand how to create for an array  
var addToObject = function (obj, key, value, index) {
 var temp = {};
 var i = 0;
 for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

   // If the indexes match, add the new item
   if (i === index && key && value) {
    temp[key] = value;
   }

   // Add the current item in the loop to the temp obj
   temp[prop] = obj[prop];

   // Increase the count
   i++;

  }
 }

 if (!index && key) {
  temp[key] = value;
 }

 return temp;

};

Comment: Then [edit] to give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Try with `map`:

```js
var arr = [{ id: "1", hello: "hello1" },{ id: "2", hello: "hello2" }];
result = arr.map(elem=>({...elem, 'bye':`bye${elem.id}`})); // with attaching the id
result2 = arr.map((elem,i)=>({...elem, 'bye':`bye${i+1}`})); // by generating id;
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below loop in your code you can get ur required output.

```
  for (var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i]["bye"] = "bye"+(i+1); 
  }
```